# trying to create a custom filter dialog using jqxgrid

Tags: jqxgrid

I am trying to create a custom filter for a single column using jqxgrid.
The example allows to add fields , but i would like to build my own set of fields.
Has anyone done this?

I then put an extra div on the column header and was going to create my own popup, but can not seem to find  the event to stop the bubble up for the sort. I can create something in the column head , but then i have to disable sorting.

I thought of turning on the filterrow, but i only want to filter on one column.

I hope i am making sense.
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable the filtering for the other columns, set their "filterable" property to false.

To customize a filter in the filter row, you may see that: [jqxGrid Filter Row](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/filterrowwithcustomitems.htm?classic).